# Meaning of partial differential in limits of integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have seen some maths problems where there is a partial differential in the limits of integration, for example: $\int_{\partial z} $

What exactly does it represent/mean? When is it used?

Comment: It might be the boundary of some domain.

Comment: ohh...ok... i get it...  Q is a region that denotes an "area", whereas $\partial{Q}$ is the "circumference" around this 2-dimensional area.  The "boundary" of the "area".  Right or wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you provide more context, it may be clearer but it may mean *"the boundary of $z$"*.

This makes sense if $z$ represents some region, e.g. a disc, and then the integral over $\partial z$ means you integrate over its boundary, in the case of the example the circle bounding the disc.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol $\partial$ is often used to denote the boundary of a set. So, for example, if $D$ is some (nice enough) set in $\mathbb C$, then $\partial D$ is the boundary of $D$, and this means that the integral over $\partial D$ is simply a line integral.