# For Green's theorem, why is the region of integration of the line integral a weird partial derivative character?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals, multiple-integral, greens-theorem

Why the weird $\partial{Q}$ notation for the integral region for Green's Theorem?

$$\int_{\partial{Q}} W \cdot ds = \iint_Q \frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{x}} - \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}} dx\ dy$$

Why not just plain "Q" instead:

$$\int_{Q} W \cdot ds = \iint_Q \frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{x}} - \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}} dx\ dy$$

If I define Q to be a rectangle region, then what's the difference?

Book says: " The sides Right, Left, Top, and Bottom of Q, with the orientations as indicated... when taken together are referred to as a "boundary".  The usual notation for this is a $\partial{Q}$".

I still say, who the heck cares...  just call it Q.  What hair am I splitting if I remove the $\partial$ character from my notes?

Answer (score 5):

Because the double integral is over some **region** $Q$ (e.g. a disc), while the line integral is over **the boundary** of $Q$ (e.g. the circle bounding that disc): they're not the same.

You can give it another name if you like, such as *"$C$, the boundary of $Q$"*, but I wouldn't call it $Q$ again since $Q$ is already used for the entire region!

For this boundary of $Q$, the notation $\partial Q$ is common.

---

Referring to my example above, you could have the unit disc $Q$:
$$Q=\left\{\left(x,y\right)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \;\vert\; x^2+y^2 \le 1\right\}$$
and its boundary, the unit circle $\partial Q$ (possibly with a chosen orientation):
$$\partial Q=\left\{\left(x,y\right)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \;\vert\; x^2+y^2 = 1\right\}$$

---

Related: [Meaning of partial differential in limits of integration?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3162982/meaning-of-partial-differential-in-limits-of-integration/3162984#3162984)